# How to check the validity of a number type input sing javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I have implemented in a form a number type input, with specified min and max :

```
<input class="qty_input" name="quantit" type="number" value="5" min="1" max="50" maxlength="2" style="width:4em;"></input>
```

The input type number works : if something else then a number is entered or if the number value is not in the specified range, the input becomes Red.

I have a javascript function that submit the form on input change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

  function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "blabla",
        type: "POST",
        data : $("#form-configurator").serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function ()
        {

        }
    });
  }
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {

    // test Validity

    doAjax();
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I would like to test before running the doAjax() function if the number input is valid.

Is there a simple way to do that, like testing a "valid" parameter of the number type input?
(it should exists as the input performs some tests itself…)

Thank you for your help,

Alex

Comment: `isNaN()` comes in handy to check whether its number or not

Comment: Can you evaluate answers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isNaN()` function to validate the input is a number or not. and you can add another if condition like

```
if(isNaN(value) || value <1 || value > 50)
 return ;
else 
    your logic
```

It will return true if that value is not a number.If it is number,then it will return false.

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Comment: This will work, but it would be better if the validation rules weren't duplicated in the HTML and JS.

Comment: @AdamHarwood check it now

Comment: that was the idea. with the type=number, the isNaN and min/max check are already performed by the html. There is no way to check the result of this test in JS instead of doing all the tests a second time?

Comment: That still hasn't solved the problem that Alexglvr has raised. However it may be that HTML5 simply doesn't provide a 'nice' way of doing this.

Comment: I then re-do the tests in JS… Using the 2 solutions mixed. It works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here a live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zueku6mo/

```
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {
    var min = $(this).attr("min") * 1;
    var max = $(this).attr("max") * 1;
    var val = $(this).val().length ? $(this).val() * 1 : NaN;
    // test Validity
    if (val >= min && val <= max) {
       $(this).css("background-color", "white");
       doAjax();
    } else {
       $(this).css("background-color", "red"); 
    }
});
```

- cast min & max attribute to number with `* 1`
- retrieve the current value and cast it to number if not empty
- do some math that failed if there is a `NaN` value
- set the background red to signal the value error

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished without duplicating the validation rules via [checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity):

```
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[type=number]')[0].checkValidity()) {
        doAjax();
    }
});
```